# Represeting timedelta object in 12'o Clock time format

Tags: python, datetime

How to represent timedelta objects in 12'o clock.

```
from datetime import timedelta

print(timedelta(hours=13))
# 13:00:00
```

How to make it display in 12'o clock format like this along with AM and PM.

```
1:00:00 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use any datetime value that corresponds to midnight to perform arithmetics with `timedelta`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> delta24h = timedelta(hours=13)
>>> (datetime.min + delta24h).strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
'01:00:00 PM'
```